# How to delete records from a table based on conditions from a joined set?

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Table : 1, Name : NdcAwp,  Columns-Ndc, AwpUnitCost  
Table : 2, Name : InvalidNdcs, Column-Ndc
```

Now, I want to delete those records from Table : 1 whose AwpUnitCost is <= 0, AwpUnitCost IS NULL and it doesn't have the same Ndc from Table : 2.

Comment: Think you might need to clarify a little. You join the tables on Name?

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you edit this to have a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
DELETE FROM NdcAwp
WHERE (AwpUnitCost <= 0
OR AwpUnitCost IS NULL)
AND Ndc NOT IN
(
SELECT Ndc
FROM InvalidNdcs
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may do what your asking.  The statement deletes from your first table where AwpUnitCost is less than or equal 0. `COALESCE` changes null values to 0, so rows with null AwpUnitCost will be included in the delete.

The `NOT IN` clause includes rows in NdcAwp that are not in InvalidNdcs, based on the Ndc value.

```
DELETE
FROM NdcAwp
WHERE COALESCE(AwpUnitCost, 0) <= 0
    AND Ndc NOT IN (SELECT Ndc FROM InvalidNdcs)
```